# Regularity gain from regular norm

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose a continuous curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb R^n$, $n>1$ is given an suppose that $|\gamma|$ is smooth. Is there a way to obtain from the regularity of $|\gamma|$ some gain in regularity for $\gamma$ e.g. some Hölder-continuity for $\gamma$?

Comment: Seems extremely unlikely to me. You can just have a very bad curve on the unit sphere.

Comment: Thanks, thats actually what I guess too - I will probably find a counter-example, i guess a Weierstrassfunction under inverse stereographic projection will do the trick.